# How to make a HTML element fill a dynamically sized container using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
   font-size: 10vw;
    width:50%;
}

button {
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input/><button>button</button>  
</div>
```

The border is just to show the div.  The input has a variable size. I've demonstrated this by using 10vw as the font size.

I would like the button to be the same height as input.

I would like the div to stay in the main flow of the page (i think that may rule out using absolute positioning tricks?) and I want the solution to be CSS only.

I'd prefer not to have to work out the size of the input - is there anyway I can get the button to fill the height of the containing div?

Comment: why not this? ...looks to me the most simple way. http://jsfiddle.net/u3upgedx/1/

Comment: @holden If you look closely, you can see the height difference between the bottom lines of the text field and the button.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u3upgedx/2/ better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add `position:relative` to the div and `position:absolute` to the button:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
input {
  font-size: 10vw;
  width: 50%;
}
button {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input/>
  <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but I guess that was just a "I downvote all answers because I don't like the question", seeing how the question has a down- and a close vote.

Comment: Brilliant - I knew i had missed something simple.  I'd tried absolute but got hung up on having to give it left / right / top / bottom etc - I didn't think of the obvious and not give it any positional info!  Thanks for your help @j08691